# Can't Run CHECKDB Against master db - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Getting the below error when attempting to run CHECKDB against master.

> Msg 5030, Level 16, State 12, Line 1
> The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.

> Msg 7926, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Check statement aborted. The database could not be checked as a database snapshot could not be created and the database or table could not be locked. See Microsoft Knowledge Base article 928518 for details of when this behavior is expected and what workarounds exist. Also see previous errors for more details.

I thought this issue had to do with [Can't Run DBCC CHECKDB on master DB - Azure Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400583/cant-run-dbcc-checkdb-on-master-db-azure-files). But, that appears not to be the case as CHECKDB runs fine against other databases with files stored on the same share.

As this is master database, I'm aware that the following **are not** possible workarounds.

- Manually create a snapshot of the database and run CHECKDB against that
- Run CHECKDB WITH TABLOCK
- Restore a copy of the database and run CHECKDB against that.

I'm at a loss for what's preventing me from completing this on this instance. I have done research and have come up empty. Including reading the KB article referenced in the error, which only applies to SQL Server 2014.

Details:

- SQL Server 2019 Clustered Instance - 1 Active / 1 Passive
- Cluster nodes are VMs

Comment: I don't think you can use `TABLOCK` against `master`, also the docs say *"DBCC CHECKDB fails when run against `master` if an internal database snapshot cannot be created."*

Comment: @BBaggins Can you provide the exact CHECKDB command you are executing when you get the error? As I understand it from your post, you're not using WITH TABLOCK, but are only stating you are aware you cannot. To clear up any confusion, that detail would be helpful.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey

Yes I'm saying that I'm aware you can't use WITH TABLOCK. 

I'm simply runing: 

DBCC CHECKDB ('master')

OR

USE master

GO

DBCC CHECKDB()

Comment: @BBaggins Thanks, I was under the impression that was what you were doing, but the actual command is not explicitly called out in your post. To avoid others from guessing, it might be a good idea to put it in there.